# Posting data and pulling the result

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am using Jquery to push pass data too a .asp page, hoping to return some data back.

I have tried sending normal string data across and it works fine.

**Jquery:**

```
          $.post("Ajax/DisplayQuery.asp", { SQLquery: $('#SQLstring').text() }, function (data1, status) { // Post query name to data page

            var str1 = data1;
            var res1 = str1.split(" | "); // Remove the pipe delimiter
            var workers1 = res1;

            alert("Columns: " + workers1);

       })
```

**.ASP page**

```
      on error resume next

    dim rs1
    Set rs1 = doSQL("request.form("SQLquery")")

    Dim fld As DAO.Field

   For Each fld In rs1.Fields
      response.Write " | " & fld.Name
   Next

   Set fld = Nothing

   if err.number > 0 then
       response.Write ("ERROR: " & err.Description)
   end if
```

From my Jquery, I'm trying to get an alert to pop-up, the pop-up does show if I send plain string text through.

The below contains an SQL query which is what I am actually passing through

```
{ SQLquery: $('#SQLstring').text() }
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  What's the problem description?  Apart from a serious security issue that doesn't seem to be part of the "question".

Comment: What do you get if you open the console and enter (or add directly above your $.post): `console.log($('#SQLstring').text())` - if that's blank then what do you get with `console.log($("#SQLstring").length)`?

Comment: Thanks got the input. .text says undefined, .length says .length is not a function at <anonymous>

Comment: Sounds like you don't have jquery installed at that point.  But unclear as would give an error on `$.post`

Comment: Its strange because I have it elsewhere on my page and it works fine.

Comment: Can you also give me more information on the security issue? and best way for me to handle it.

Comment: The security issue is that you're letting the client-side directly specify a SQL query to be executed, without any kind of filtering. It's just asking to be hacked.

Comment: As it stands, any user can drop down the console and enter `$.ajax("Ajax/DisplayQuery.asp", { SQLquery: "select * from passwords"})` or something more malicious such as `drop table passwords`.  No need to even add in the usual SQL injection hacks as you're running whatever is passed.  It's too big a subject to cover here.

Comment: Anyway as to your actual issue currently, it's still a bit unclear. You've said "I'm trying to get an alert to pop-up, the pop-up does show if I send plain string text through."...but your ASP code _does_ send plain-text already. And if such text is received correctly, in theory there should be no issue in displaying it - here's a stripped-down demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wnzq8dk9/ . So when you say you're "trying", we assume maybe something goes wrong with (some version of) your attempt? You'll need to give more details of specifically what the issue is, before we can help you.

Comment: e.g. perhaps it fails only when a certain query is run, or when certain data is returned? Have you tried to debug this client-side (using your browser's Developer Tools to monitor the Console for errors, and monitor the Network tool to see if the AJAX succeeds, and exactly what the server responds with)? Have you tried any kind of debugging of the ASP code on the server-side? It's unclear what investigation you've done, or what results you're getting, and with what data inputs. We can't run your code, so you need to investigate it, narrow down the problem, and give a detailed report.

Comment: Im still fairly new to all this. So exuse my limited knowledge. Using the console I do get the following message: DisplayQuery.asp 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: @ADyson from the comments/tests above, it looks like the issue is that  `$('#SQLstring').text()` is returning blank, but `$('#SQLstring').length` is "undefined" which is a bit odd

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error) means that the server-side code crashed, but doesn't give you the underlying reason. If ASP is configured to send error messages in the response, you may be able to see details of the error by looking at the request to DisplayQuery.asp in the Network tool, clicking on the request to open it up, and going to the Response tab. (If ASP isn't configured to do that, maybe consider setting it up that way temporarily so you can see the error. Or you may be able to see it in the Event Viewer on the server already.)

Comment: This line `doSQL("request.form("SQLquery")")` doesn't look right - do you mean `doSQL(request.form("SQLquery"))` ?  But then it wouldn't work if you "send normal string across" (exactly where/what does this statement apply to?)

Comment: Thank you both for the help. @ADyson, I followed your steps to view the Network in the inspect element tool. Fantastic! Its helped me fix the issue. I would detail the resolution here but not enough characters

Comment: Great. If you have a solution, post it in the Answers section below - that's what it's for...answers to the question! You're allowed, and encouraged, to answer your own question, and others can then upvote it if they find it useful in their own situation. _Don't_ add your answer to the original question post. The answer is not part of the question, they are separate!

Comment: That's not valid VBScript, Classic ASP does not use VB style strongly typed variables.

Comment: Ive added the solution to my initial post - Thanks @Lankymart, I finally identified exactly what you just said. Cheers

Comment: @tryer "Ive added the solution to my initial post"...that's not how this site is meant to work. Please see my previous comment. The site follows a clear Question & Answer format. Questions in the questions section, and answers (including answers to your own question) in the answers  section. Please don't muddy the two. If you add, and then accept, your own answer, it increases the chances of others finding it when they have similar issues. Whereas right now, to the search engine, it looks like your question has no solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - Ive removed it off the question and posted an answer. If you feel I should add more to it please let me know

Answer (score 1):

@ADyson suggested I review the Network tab in the inspect element tool. This helped identify 2 issues in the code.

Syntax problem and needed to remove the quotes leaving the following:

```
doSQL(request.form("SQLquery"))
```

I also had to remove As DAO.Field from this line:

```
Dim fld As DAO.Field
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that the structure you have is just **begging** to have somebody pass a "delete all tables" SQL query to your site. Allowing users to pass in a SQL query to be run is terrible, terrible security.

Comment: @StephenR The page is used in an internal environment so we'll be okay. Although it has got my attention to me working to to implement better security. Any suggestion on where to start looking for solutions?

Comment: It's a basic principle: "Never trust user-provided data". That includes anything provided via POST or GET, as those can be easily faked. It's way more than I could put in a mere comment; but at minimum, use parameterized queries. I can't imagine a safe way to let the user (or Ajax) just pass in entire queries that get run on the back end.  Search "parameterized queries" and "sql injection" for good places to start